# Why did a single predictive disk failure cause a RAID6 array to fail (and how do we stop it from happening again)?

Tags: dell-poweredge, dell-perc

We have a Dell PowerEdge R740xd with 16 HDDs and 2 SSDs. The 16 HDDs had a 15 disk RAID6 array (with one hot spare). It hosts a number of VMs (using HyperV) and last Monday all the VMs failed. Upon investigation we discovered that disk 4 was having predictive failures and three other disks were showing as "foreign config" resulting in the RAID6 disk being offline.

Attempts to import the foreign config disks back into the array would return the array to degraded state but any time the array attempted to relevel, we would lose the array again with three disks (but not necessarily the same 3 disks) showing as "foreign config".

After 3 days our next day replacement disks arrived and we replaced disk 4 and attempted to rebuild the array but the same thing kept happening.

After much back and forth and attempts to escalate we were eventually told that it was our fault the virtual disk failed because we "didn't remove the predictive failure disk soon enough". Looking at the logs, disk 4 entered predictive failure on the 16th Feb and the host and VMs all failed on the 24th Feb.

This is probably a naive question but how can a single "predictive failure" bring down a RAID6 array that should be able to tolerate 2 disk failures without data loss?

Apparently if we install OpenManage, it can tell disks that are predicting failure to drop out of the array. Another naive question, why isn't that functionality built into the RAID controller if there's a risk of data loss in this situation?

Anyway:

- We have wiped the virtual disk and rebuilt it with a hot spare
- We now have alerting turned on (we previously assumed RAID6, a hot spare and monthly checks would be sufficient to avoid downtime)
- We will install OpenManage and set up the smart error functionality

Final, and most concrete question, is there anything else we should (reasonably) do?

Comment: That's kinda messed up. I've never seen a RAID6 array fail in that way before, especially not because of a single predicted failure. I'd be going back to whoever "they" is who told you this and asking them to explain in more detail about what happened, in writing. Do it under the guise of making sure it doesn't happen again, or whatever. But I feel there's an important piece of this puzzle missing.

Comment: As for "why isn't this built into the raid controller" you'll find it's because a raid controller is very dumb and should ultimately be left alone for as much as possible so you're not having to push out firmware updates to fix some alerting bug. Leave that to higher level software that can be updated and maintained easier.

Comment: When I read 16 disk RAID6 I think to myself, why? 16 disk RAID6 screams for getting corrupt. Please, inform yourself about harddisks, filesystems and random computer errors and never use a 16 disk RAID5 or RAID6 again. You should use RAID1, but better is you use modern filesystems with RAID functions like BTRFS or ZFS. PS I hope you have a backup

Comment: PPS replace all disks immediately or your RAID array will be fatally destroyed in the near future, the reason for your broken RAID6 is, that there are more than 1 disk faulty but your checks don't show this, please, create a new RAID1 array (better use BTRFS or ZFS RAID1) from scratch and use a backup to refill it